# VBA Macro To Format All Headings in Document As Bold

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to automate a search/replace of headings in a Word 2013 document (note, these are not Word style headings but simply text typed in uppercase with a colon). For example:

CHIEF COMPLAINT:

PHYSICAL EXAMINATION:

The search and replace is only to format the headings to bold, which otherwise has to be done manually, otherwise the heading text remains the same. There is no way to know which headings will be in the document (or if any at all), which order or whether the first line of the document will include a heading or not.

A manual search/replace for: ^13(*:)

To this: ^p\1

Works, except if the first instance is at the beginning of the file (no return).

The macro I've been using is this:

```
Sub BoldHeadings()
'
' BoldHeadings Macro
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Format = False
  .Forward = True
  .MatchWildcards = True
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .Text = "^13(*:)"
  .Replacement.Text = "^p\1"
  .Replacement.Font.Bold = True
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

As stated, this works fine except if the first instance is at the beginning of the file. Is there another way I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub BoldHeadings()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  .InsertBefore vbCr
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Font.Bold = True
    .Text = "^13*:"
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Format = True
    .Forward = True
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
  .Paragraphs.First.Range.Delete
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Much thanks! This _almost_ works. It takes care of the instance at the beginning of the document issue perfectly, but fails if the heading has nothing after it (no matter where the heading is in the document). For example, a heading with a list following below it -- in other words, another return right after the colon. This causes both the heading and the list text below it to be bolded. Any ideas?

Comment: The code I posted won't bold anything after the colon. If you're finding such content, that's because it was already formatted that way. That said, you might try changing the Find expression to "^13[!^13]@:"

Comment: The new expression does the trick! Thanks! I beg to differ, however, regarding your other statements. The first expression _does_ bold all intervening text from one header to the next and nothing was already formatted.

Try it on a mock document, if you don't believe me. Type 3 uppercase headers with a colon. On header 1, follow the colon with 2 spaces and some sentence case text: "HEADER1:  Blah blah blah." On HEADER2:, don't type any text after the colon, but instead hit return and type a numbered list below the header. Follow that with HEADER3: and more sentence case text after the colon.

Comment: ...continued...Run your macro exactly as you posted it above with the first Find expression, and you'll find that all the headers in the document are bold as hoped for, but that all intervening text between HEADER2 and HEADER3 (i.e., the numbered list) will be bold, too.

I assume this is due to either the return after the HEADER2 colon or the returns in the numbered list, or some combination of both.

No matter, though. Your second Find expression is perfection. Thanks again!

Comment: The original Find expression - which is essentially your own - finds everything between a paragraph break and a colon. The problem with that approach is that using * means it'll start at the first paragraph break and continue from there until it finds a colon, no matter how many paragraphs later that might be. The replacement expression restricts the found range's scope to a single paragraph.

Comment: Thank you. Your earlier comment was just rather adamant about how "the code [you] posted won't bold anything after the colon" and if it does it was "because it was already formatted that way." Neither of those statements was the case. I was simply pointing that out.

Comment: That statement, too was correct, but its your understanding of what was going on that was lacking. That problem will only occur if the only thing after your colon is a paragraph break. With your Find expression, everything from the first paragraph break after a colon until the next colon is found will be bolded. Anything *between* the colon and the paragraph break immediately after it won't be bolded, though.

Comment: My understanding is just fine. And you in fact are echoing exactly what I said in my 2-part comment. I specifically stated it was a return immediately after the colon that was probably causing it. And it was _your_ find expression being used, not mine. You also didn't clarify your "nothing will be bolded after the colon" comment -- until now. You just said "nothing after the colon" period and also "already formatted." Both wrong. Let's just drop it. I've moved on to an array anyway.